# Selecting heighest number in sql with the same id

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to select max transaction_num from my table tbl_loan and group it by c_id to avoid duplicate of c_id.

here is my query

```html
SELECT * FROM `tbl_loan` WHERE transaction_num IN (SELECT max(transaction_num) max_trans FROM tbl_loan GROUP BY c_id)
```

and my output is [image]

still have duplicate c_id.

Comment: aren't `SELECT max(transaction_num) max_trans FROM tbl_loan GROUP BY c_id` enough? why there is a need of subquery?

Comment: I need to select *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, and correct me if I'm wrong. The transaction number appears to be sequential per each C_ID whenever a new transaction happens.  There is also the "I_ID" column which appears to be an auto-incrementing column which does not duplicate.  It appears your transaction number is sequentially 1, 2, 3, etc per C_ID for simple counting purposes, so everyone starts with a 1, and those with more have 2nd and possibly 3rd and more...

So, if this is accurate and you want the most recent per C_ID, you really want the max "I_ID" per C_ID because multiple records will exist with a value of 2, 3, etc...

try this.

```
SELECT 
      TL.* 
   FROM 
      tbl_loan TL 
         JOIN ( SELECT C_ID, max(I_ID) maxI_ID
                      FROM tbl_loan 
                      GROUP BY c_id) MaxPer
            on TL.I_ID = MaxPer.MaxI_ID
```

So, from your data for C_ID = 55, you have I_ID = 61 (trans num = 1) and 62 (trans num = 2).  So for ID = 55, you want the transaction I_ID = 62 which represents the second transaction.

For C_ID = 70, it has I_IDs of 77 & 78, of which will grab I_ID = 78.

The rest only have a single trans num and will get their only single entry id.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL MAX with GROUP BY clause**

To find the maximum value for every group, you use the MAX function with the GROUP BY clause in a SELECT statement.

You use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    *, MAX(transaction_num)
FROM
    tbl_loan
GROUP BY c_id
ORDER BY MAX(transaction_num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it like this

Your query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_loan` WHERE transaction_num IN (SELECT max(transaction_num) max_trans FROM tbl_loan GROUP BY c_id)
```

Lets say your subquery returns one transaction_num of 20.  This 20 can be the same for multiple c_id's.

So your outer query is then running

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_loan` WHERE transaction_num IN (20)
```

and returning all those results.